Select non-syntactic names of a data frame when name is a variable
I have a data frame where some of the column names are non-syntactic. I want to select a range of these columns, but I am trying to do so inside a function. That is, the non-syntactic names which I want to select on are provided as variables to the function.
Here is an example:
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a = "a", b = "b", `1` = "c", `2` = "d")

f <- function(df) {
  select(df, `1`:`2`)
}

g <- function(df, var) {
  select(df, all_of(var):`2`)
}

The output is:
> f(df)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `1`   `2`  
  <chr> <chr>
1 c     d    

> g(df, var = 1)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  a     b     `1`   `2`  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     b     c     d 

> g(df, var = `1`)
Error in `select()`:
i In argument: `all_of(var)`.
Caused by error:
! object '1' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I am trying to implement the functionality of g, but I want the output of f (in this specific example).
It seems that by all_of(var) I am referencing the column index; I would rather make a reference to the non-syntactic name of the third column of the data frame. How can I reference a non-syntactic name in a select-call when that name is stored as a variable?

Why are you doing this? It's possible but it seems like it will practically guarantee these kinds of headaches, as well as surprising bugs.

The issue is not related to the use of a non-syntactic column name, i.e. you will get same error when you do:
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df <- tibble(a = "a", b = "b", `1` = "c", `2` = "d")

g <- function(df, var) {
  select(df, all_of(var):`2`)
}

g(df, var = b)
#> Error in `select()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `all_of(var)`.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! object 'b' not found

The issue is simply that when you want to pass an unquoted column name to a function you have to take care of that using an quote-and-unquote pattern which can be simplified in one step using curly-curly aka {{ (see here and  here), i.e. you can do:
g <- function(df, var) {
  select(df, {{ var }}:`2`)
}

g(df, var = `1`)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   `1`   `2`  
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 c     d

The only special thing about non-syntactic column names is that we have to wrap them inside backticks.

The first set of curly braces "look inside" var, and find that it evaluates to ` 1 ` ; the second set of braces then evaluate ` 1 ` as the non-syntactic column name. Is that correct? I think I should read https://r4ds.hadley.nz/functions.html#data-frame-functions to understand why your solution works. (The formatting of 1 in this comment isn't working properly; I will see if I can fix it later.)

Nop. The issue has nothing to do with the use of non-syntactic column names, i.e. you will get the same error when you do g(df, var = b). It's simply that when we pass an unquoted column name to a function that we have to take special care and {{ is one way to do so. See e.g. here.

Thank you for your solution, explanation and references to where I can learn more!
